# SQL Server Stored Procedure to get website text

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, api, stored-procedures

Wondering if this is possible.

I need to write a SQL Server stored procedure to get some text from a Web API page. The page is https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets

It's perfectly fine if this is just gathered as one long string, I'll do the cutting to put it into different columns myself using T-SQL.

If this is not possible, is there any other way to accomplish this? I rather not use SSIS, but best practices are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server isn't meant as a web querying engine, you need to re-think the design here to include a middle-tier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With three helper functions listed below, it's not so bad.

The following returns 2,926 records in 2.578 seconds (including the download).

I should add the Parse and Parse-Row Function could be in-line if you'd rather

You can pivot the following based on RowNr if desired.

**Example**

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe Invoke-WebRequest "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets" -OutFile "c:\working\getmarkets.txt"',no_output

Declare @S varchar(max); 
Select @S = BulkColumn FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\working\getmarkets.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) x; 

Select RowNr = A.RetSeq
      ,Item  = replace(C.Pos1,'"','')
      ,Value = replace(C.Pos2,'"','')
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@S,'{','}') A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.RetVal,',') B
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Row](B.RetVal,'":') C
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Parse UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

**The Extract UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

**And Finally a Parse ROW UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Row] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
          ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
    Where @String is not null
)
```

> **EDIT - Just for fun I tossed in a PIVOT**

```
Select *
 From (
        Select RowNr = A.RetSeq
              ,Item  = replace(C.Pos1,'"','')
              ,Value = replace(C.Pos2,'"','')
         From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@S,'{','}') A
         Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.RetVal,',') B
         Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-Row](B.RetVal,'":') C
      ) Src
 Pivot (max(value) for Item in ([MarketCurrency],[BaseCurrency],[MarketCurrencyLong],[BaseCurrencyLong],[MinTradeSize],[MarketName],[IsActive],[Created],[Notice],[IsSponsored],[LogoUrl])) p
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: this is simply brilliant, thank you so much john! The Pivot is really welcome too! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ImperialBert Happy to help ... and thanks for the grin